In a book, what are the pros and cons of starting chapters on the left hand page?
Usually chapters in printed books start on the right hand page of an open spread, known as the recto. This is so even when most chapters contain only two or three pages and indeed even when some of them contain only a single page. So as to ensure that the rule is followed, some pages are kept blank.
But this is not universal. For example some textbooks will start chapters on the left hand page (known as the verso), especially when a lot of two-page graphics are used. Indeed there is no way to get a two-page graphic to start on the first page of a chapter, if this is what you need to do, unless you start the chapter on the verso.
Assume we have a book that consists exclusively, or almost exclusively, of two page chapters; and assume it doesn't contain many graphics, and certainly no two-page graphics.
My question is as follows.
For such a book, what are the UX pros and cons of taking the unusual design decision to start chapters on the left?
To start this off:

A pro is that the reader sees the whole of a chapter, at least in the case of most chapters, in one spread. Combined with the title, this may give the reader the positive feeling that he knows what the chapter will be about and how much it's going to say about what it's about.

A con is that this sort of presentation is unusual. It may jar with a reader who perceives it as peculiar.


Note that this question is not about books in general. It is about the specific case of a book in which at least the large majority of chapters are only two pages long.

You need to consider the case of "flipping through the pages" in searchmode of a certain chapter. You would hold the book in the right hand and flip with the thumb of the left hand until you reach the desired chapter -- and here it is necessary to have the title of the chapter on the right-side page to allow the reader to ascertain having found the correct chapter.
Alternatives:

Add chapter names at the header or footer on the right-side page.
Use full page title pages for each chapter - this would probably be "wasting" pages but could also be considered to be a styling element, depending on the content of the book (could be fitting for poems for example).
Obviously: Start the chapter on the right-side page then the second page is on the backside. Additional benefit if the title is also shown on the header or footer of the left page: Flipping through the pages holding the book in the left hand and flipping with the right thumb will also show the title on the left-side page -- it supports both handedness  so to say.

The pro you mentioned is countered by the reading habit to "bend" the book pages to only see the current page. Your suggestion is not a universal pro always applying, just on a case-to-case (or reader-to-reader) basis.
General words of wisdom:
If you consider to deviate from the default, be mindful about the consequences: Your book will be considered to be "special". If you want that effect - go ahead. If you do not want the user having to adapt and needing to decide if shi likes or dislikes that layout instead of just having a book the readers are totally used to - don't do it.
